# Can Google Kubernetes run Apache Mesos frameworks on top of it?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesos, mesosphere

I was wondering if Google Kubernetes is able to run Apache Mesos frameworks, such as Hadoop or Cassandra etc.., like applications running on top of it. If yes or no, please justify your answers. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no - you can run applications in containers on kubernetes, and you can run kubernetes on mesos.

In fact, Cassandra is one of the [standard kubernetes examples.](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples/cassandra) And there is an example of [kubernetes on mesos](https://github.com/mesosphere/kubernetes-mesos).

Comment: According to my readings, people are working on running Kubernetes on top of Mesos to take advantage of the other Mesos' frameworks, so that we can run hadoop beside Kubernetes and take advantage of the two. So if Kubernetes alone can run Hadoop, why would we even be using Mesos? and are we able to run Hadoop in a Container on top of Kubernetes?

Comment: Mesos is a general purpose distributed computing framework. You would implement your own applications using its primitives, though it /can/ be used in a similar role to kubernetes. Kubernetes is a declaritive tool that will help manage deployments of container based (read: docker) applications. Anything in a container is a valid target for kubernetes management.

Comment: I still dont get the advantage of running kubernetes on top of mesos if kubernetes alone can do the trick. At the beginning, I thought that the reason behind this was to take advantage of running other frameworks like hadoop alongside kubernetes on mesos, but then it turned out that kubernetes can run anything inside a container, hadoop for example, so that reason is no longer valid. Got my point?

Comment: This answer is ambiguous if not plain wrong. Mesos is meant to do this, yes, K8S not.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas -- it's good to have someone authoritative helping out here, so thanks for the input. Can you expand a bit? (I can see the ambiguity, that bit is ok, but I can't understand the second sentence without further expansion.

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas -- Let me please change the question. Why can't we run Hadoop inside Kubernetes? And in what programming language should Kubernetes' apps be written, is it only Go? Thank you.

Comment: @AhmedAzri -- no, that can't be true, look at all the examples: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/examples, plus, I'm currently working on a project that uses kubernetes and I'm writing it in javascript on node.js

Comment: @EngineerDollery Yes right, thanks. However, I'm still wondering why can't we run Hadoop with Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0):

No. In fact it's the other way round. Concerning benefits see also my presentation [here](https://speakerdeck.com/mhausenblas/can-i-have-mesos-and-kubernetes).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But why not? Can't we run Spark for example inside a container on top of Kubernetes, knowing that Spark is a standard Kubernetes example?

Comment: Thanks for helping out here. On stack overflow we prefer to have answers spelled out in full on this site. That's because offiste links eventually become stale and the answer then becomes a lot less helpful to readers. Also, some of us can't follow links like yours in work, which is where a lot of people use SO, so an inline expansion would help us to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

The new "DaemonSet" abstraction in Kubernetes provides great support for running data processing and storage systems like HDFS and others relying on daemon-based architectures...

"Users might want to implement a sharded datastore in their (Kubernetes) cluster. A few nodes in the cluster, labeled ‘app=datastore’, might be responsible for storing data shards, and pods running on these nodes might serve data. This architecture requires a way to bind pods to specific nodes, so it cannot be achieved using a Replication Controller. A DaemonSet is a convenient way to implement such a datastore."

See: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.1/docs/design/daemon.md

Answer (score 0):

There's conflicting answers, here. Let me try to clarify.

Kubernetes and Mesos are both frameworks/platforms that are more like pets than cattle. In fact, they're a little bit of both.

- Both are backed by consistent, replicated, stateful storage (etcd/zookeeper).
- Both have master components that can be replicated (tho the k8s solution for this is somewhat immature and complicated).
- Both have agents that run on nodes that are not replicated and can be scaled out, to run other applications.

Running pets is something that Kubernetes CAN now do, with the recent DaemonSets functionality, but it wasn't really designed with this capability in mind. And, IMO, it doesn't quite do well enough yet for production use. Kubernetes was originally designed to run cattle-like replicated containers. However, there is active development to improve running pet-like applications, especially to support bootstrapping, to run Kubernetes itself on Kubernetes nodes, using DaemonSets.

Mesos, on the other hand, was designed explicitly to make these pet-like distributed systems easier to write and manage. It does this by effectively outsourcing the consistent state management, and providing a standard interface against with to write a framework/controller which can respond to cluster events with custom logic. It doesn't just treat every application the same way, it lets you program your own event handler code, specific to your pet-like application. This allows for more control. Obviously, cattle-like applications don't need this extra control. So to run cattle-like applications on Mesos you use an intermediate framework, like Marathon or Kubernetes, to implement the scheduling and event handling logic in a generic, declaratively configurable way.

Disclaimer: I work on the [Kubernetes-Mesos project](https://github.com/mesosphere/kubernetes-mesos) for running Kubernetes on Mesos/DCOS.